# Use variable or item in list as part of code (not as string or variable) or variable itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, sqlalchemy

I have a list of string.

```
list=['cretd_dt','rcvd_dt']
```

The actual code is:

```
query = table.update().values(
        cretd_dt = Join_All_Dates.iloc[index]['cretd_dt'],
        rcvd_dt= Join_All_Dates.iloc[index]['rcvd_dt'])
```

I want the `cretd_dt=` and `rcvd_dt=` to be used from inside the list. That is if the list has a,b, then inside the query it must be .`values( a=join[index]['a'])` etc.

```
list=['a','b']
query = table.update().values(
            a = Join_All_Dates.iloc[index]['a'],
            b= Join_All_Dates.iloc[index]['b'])
```

Comment: Why can't you use index of list for that? like `a = Join_All_Dates.iloc[index]list[0],  b= Join_All_Dates.iloc[index]list[1])` will work if the size of the list going to remain same. And `list` is not supposed to use as a variable name in python.

Comment: the list size can vary. and in a=Join_All_Dates, variable a can also change. it can be b or c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a `dict` and unpack it as arguments to `values()`:

```
# Don't shadow builtins such as list
the_list = ['a', 'b']
query = table.update().values(**{k: Join_All_Dates.iloc[index][k] for k in the_list})
```

though you don't need to unpack, since `Update.values()` accepts a `dict` as a positional argument directly as well.

Comment: does it work if there are more than 2 elements in the list?

Comment: It'll work for any amount of items (as supported by your DBMS etc.) The dict-comprehension simply iterates over the list.